# how to use sed to modify xml file?

Tags: shell, sed

The origin text as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://statc.dd.me/resources/gege/editresume/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=4004"/>
```

I want to replace `"http://statc.dd.me/resources/gege/editresume/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=4004"` by
`"bootstrap.min.css"` in above text", and I have tried use command

`sed -n {'1,35s/.*\/\(.*\)?.*/\1/pg'}` to filter out bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: is this what you need `sed -n '1,35s/.*\/\(.*\)?.*/<link rel="stylesheet" href="\1"\/>/p'`? also, use xml parser instead..

Comment: I take an example, I neeed to use  sed to change "aaa bb  cc specific word" to "aaa bb specific word specific word", and I can't by terns of "sed 's/cc/specific word/' ". I can only filter out "specific word", then use "specific word" filtered to replace "cc". thank you!

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand that... I suggest to add all sample inputs with expected outputs to question... you can also check out http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/topics for examples in case they can help you